# ValueError usupported format character 'd' with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have code like this:

```
print "company_id = %d" % company_id
...
db.cursor.execute("insert into person (company_id, first, last, type) values (%d, '%s', '%s', %d);", (company_id, name[0], name[1], type))
```

I get the following output:

```
company_id = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "./GetPeople.py", line 125, in insertPerson
    db.cursor.execute("insert into person (company_id, first, last, type) values (%d, '%s', '%s', %d);",
```

Why can it print out the first line but it gives an error for the `db.cursor.execute()` call?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The single quotes around the %s placeholders are incorrect and the %d isn't used [as per the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Change

```
db.cursor.execute("insert into person (company_id, first, last, type) values (%d, '%s', '%s', %d);", (company_id, name[0], name[1], type))
```

to

```
db.cursor.execute("insert into person (company_id, first, last, type) values (%s, %s, %s, %s);", (company_id, name[0], name[1], type))
```

Answer (score 5):

From  the [Psycopg FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions):

> Q: I can’t pass an integer or a float parameter to my query: it says a
>   number is required, but it is a number!
>
> A: In your query string, you always have to use %s placeholders, even when passing a number. All Python objects are converted by Psycopg in
>   their SQL representation, so they get passed to the query as strings.
>   See Passing parameters to SQL queries.

Replace the `%d` with `%s`.